# Specify Excel increments in autofill

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autofill

I'm looking to use excel autofill to complete my formulas in a specific way. My formula is:

```
=IF(Sheet1!E2<$A$2,$A$2,IF(Sheet1!E2>$A$3,A$3,Sheet1!E2))
```

I drag down to autofill all instances of `E2` --> `E3` and so on, as I'd like.

I also want to drag right to make incremental formulae where all instances of `A$2` --> `B$2` and so on, as well as all instances of `E2` --> `F2` and so on:

```
=IF(Sheet1!F2<$B$2,$B$2, IF(Sheet1!F2>$B$3,B$3, Sheet1!F2))
```

Instead, I get this:

```
=IF(Sheet1!F2<$A$2,$A$2,IF(Sheet1!F2>$A$3,B$3,Sheet1!F2))
```

I'm aware that there are some macros that can do this for me, but I'm not very familiar with excel macros and I wouldn't know how to edit them for my specific issue.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think your first two formulas don't line up with what you are writing, but it looks like you are freezing the cell your formula's evaluating. If you just want to freeze the column, use $A2, if you just want to freeze the row, use A$2, if you want freedom in both directions, use A2

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 extra $ signs in your formula.
Below formula should work fine for you I guess.
`=IF(Sheet1!E2<A$2,A$2,IF(Sheet1!E2>A$3,A$3,Sheet1!E2))`

(In addition to comment of @Euler's Disgraced Stepchild, I recommend you to search when to use $ sign in excel formulas. It is something essential in Excel)